# Poetry lock - empty hashes

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am doing

```
poetry lock
```

Then I open the `poetry.lock` file and see that the `metadata.files` block does not contain hashes:

```
[metadata.files]
aiohttp = []
aiosignal = []
apscheduler = []
...
```

Before, it wasn't like that. What could be the reasons for empty hashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running into this issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5970

Just upgrade to poetry 1.1.14 or the prereleases for the 1.2 series.

Comment: Thanks. In addition, it was necessary to do `poetry cache clear pypi --all`